# setProperty is not a function(...)

Tags: javascript, gwt

When I use

```
$wnd.document.getElementById('id');
```

It works successfully and I get the element. But, when I try to set `property` like this:

```
$wnd.document.getElementById('id').setProperty("Property","value");
```

It brings me error :

> Uncaught TypeError: $wnd.document.getElementById(...).setProperty is
>   not a function(…)

With what mistake in my code can it be chained?

Comment: I can set property in this way:  `elem =$wnd.document.getElementById('id');  elem[property] = value;`  But i want to know, for what reason this path doesn't work:  `$wnd.document.getElementById('id').setProperty("Property","value"); `

Comment: In IE i caught exception  `Object doesn't support property or method 'setProperty'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are executing this code inside a JSNI method, means it is Javascript. The method `setProperty` is only available for a javascript **style** element, and has nothing todo with the GWT method `setPropertyString()` or similar.

So this:

```
elem =$wnd.document.getElementById('id');  
elem[property] = value;
```

equals this:

```
$wnd.document.getElementById('id').setAttribute("property","value");
```

`setProperty` would work for Style properties like this:

`$wnd.document.getElementById('id').style.setProperty("color","blue");`

Answer (score 0):

i opened the project by liveServer ... the error disapeared
try it ..